# how to hide particular option in select tag in mui react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

in that select tag by default **Click** is a disabled option and hidden.so when I want to click the select that time I don't want to show the disable option in the list so that's why I give hidden attribute.so how is it possible to set an option which is showing by default and when user want to click the select tag that disable option should not visible like in normal select tag if you give any option disable hidden property ,I also give that two property but hidden is not working .How can I do that

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@mui/material/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@mui/material/FormControl';
import Select from '@mui/material/Select';

export default function BasicSelect() {
  const [age, setAge] = React.useState('');

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setAge(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box sx={{ minWidth: 120 }}>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Age</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
          id="demo-simple-select"
          value={age}
          label="Age"
          onChange={handleChange}
        >
          <MenuItem value={10} disabled hidden>Click</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={11}>Ten</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={20}>Twenty</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={30}>Thirty</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try placing `style={{ display: "none" }}` on the MenuItem you want hidden.

Comment: then in Option by default Click is not present,but it should be present

Comment: So your use case is that you want to control when to show/hide a particular option? or am I understanding it incorrectly?

Comment: Here is a sandbox version of your code. https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-water-tej45e?file=/src/App.js
What I understand is that, by default a disabled value is selected on the Select. But when a user opens the select, they should not be show that disabled option.